# Web Share API sharing files Permission Denied

Tags: web-share

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I think there should be more documentation or better error descriptions for this [Web Share API](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/).

I'm trying to share the following file

```
{
  lastModified: 1622843015507
  lastModifiedDate: Fri Jun 04 2021 16:43:35 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) {}
  name: "60b1d17b7f2cd71c8307fae2"
  size: 37835
  type: "image/png"
  webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

using

```
await navigator.share({
    text: 'TEST',
    files: [file],
  });
```

I've made sure that the type is a permitted type, but I keep getting `DOMException: Permission denied`. I really don’t understand what should I be looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I think the issue you're facing is the fact that your file name doesn't have an extension. Try adding `.png` to the file name, it should automagically work.

```js
const file = new File(['hello'], 'hello.png', { type: 'image/png' });
await navigator.share({ files: [file] });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a pdf file I had stored as a Blob. Kept getting the 'Permission Denied' error:

```
 if (pdfBlob && pdfBlob.type && pdfBlob.type.startsWith('application/pdf')) {
        const fileName = report.id.toString(); 
        const file = new File([pdfBlob], fileName);        
        const files = [file];       
        if (navigator.canShare({files})) {                
            navigator.share({
                files: files,
            })
                .then(() => console.log('PDF shared successfully'))
                .catch(error => console.error('PDF sharing failed:', error));
        } else {
            console.log('PDF sharing is not supported in this browser.');
        }
    }
    else {
        console.error('Invalid Blob: Not a PDF file.');
    }
```

I was missing two things:

1. Adding the extension to the file name, like [@François Beaufort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/422957/fran%C3%A7ois-beaufort) said:
   "Try adding .png to the file name, it should automagically work."
2. Including the proper file type as the third parameter, in my case: {type: 'application/pdf'}.

The end result:

```
const file = new File([pdfBlob],  report.id.toString() + '.pdf', {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I see you have gotten some feedback on the [issue](https://github.com/w3c/web-share/issues/205) that you raised already. Here is a concrete example that hopefully helps you get started:

```js
if (navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare({ files: filesArray })) {
  navigator.share({
    files: filesArray,
    title: 'Vacation Pictures',
    text: 'Photos from September 27 to October 14.',
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Share was successful.'))
  .catch((error) => console.log('Sharing failed', error));
} else {
  console.log(`Your system doesn't support sharing files.`);
}
```

One way of getting a files array (the `filesArray` above) is through an `<input type=files>` element. See the [official example](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/demos/share-files.html) for this.